# Edit some rows of JSON data in angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I am consuming JSON data dynamically to display on Angular UI(shown in jpg file below)[1]. I want to give ability to edit only specific rows of it when user clicks particular values in JSON output.

Problem: I can edit the whole JSON data but not specific rows of it. Any leads would be of great help.

Example JSON : { "key1": value1, "key2": value2}. I want to make value2 editable to the user and not key1, key2 and value1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGvuU.jpg

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box way of doing this. You could display editable values in a different block than non editable ones, or you could let the user do whatever and perform some check afterwards (or even perform these checks "live" for a better user experience) and display an error if user changed something he shouldn't have.

Comment: You can map the JSON to an object in the component, and in the HTML display object data based on its keys. This way you can update only the key that is being edited. When you send the JSON back to the server, you should send it whole though.